# Shuffle and sorting after combiner

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a mapper, a combiner and a reducer. As I know, combiner comes before shuffle & sorting phase. But, in my case, the output from the mapper is coming sorted to the combiner.

```
hadoop jar hadoop_streeaming.jar \
        -input some_folder \
        -output some_folder \
        -mapper mapper.py \
        -combiner combine.py \
        -file mapper.py \
        -file combine.py
```

I want the results from Mapper comes unsorted to the Combiner.

For example:

I have this text:

```
mary
has
a
big
cat
```

this text is coming to the **combiner** in this form:

```
a
big
cat
has
mary
```

Bur, I don't want the output sorted before combiner.

Comment: I think you'll need to elaborate your question, it isn't clear what the _issue_ is?

Comment: I've added more information

Comment: Combiner can run more than one time, it can also run after shuffle and sort phase.

Comment: Why you dont want the mapper output to be sorted?